# Using did +verb instead of the past form of the verb

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense, time, do-support

I have a sentence:

> No sooner did we get to our car than the thunderstorm began.

Is it okay to use **did we get**? It sounds very natural for me, but I am not sure whether or not such grammar construction is allowed. So is it right to write this way instead of **we got**?

Comment: Not only is it OK, but **No sooner we got** would actually be incorrect.  I'm not sure I know the name for the actual kind of construction used here, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sooner did we get ...

In modern English the use of the verb to do plus another verb is used as a way of avoiding having to reverse the normal subject-verb order of a sentence.

The alternative 'No sooner got we ...' is archaic, it occurs in Shakespearean English.

So, in Modern English whenever the normal subject-verb-object would be changed by an adverbial clause or by a question the verb to do is used to avoid this and maintain the normal order.

> Do you understand?

As opposed to:

> Understand you?

No longer do we use this word order

As opposed to:

> No longer use we this word order.

Comment: So, is this right: **No sooner did we get to our car than the thunderstorm began.**?

Comment: <<In modern English the use of the verb to do plus another verb is used as a way of avoiding having to reverse the normal subject-verb order of a sentence.>> Hence, "**No sooner did we get to our car than the thunderstorm began.**" is wrong and "**No sooner we got to our car than the thunderstorm began.**" is right. Did I get the point?

Comment: No sooner did we get to our car .... is correct.

Comment: However, 'As soon as we got to our car the thunderstorm began' works.

Comment: Look out for the word than.

Comment: You say that <<No sooner **did we get** to our car .... is correct.>>, but at the same time you say that <<in Modern English whenever the normal **subject-verb-object** would be changed by an adverbial clause or by a question the verb to do is used to avoid this and maintain the normal order.>>. So verb do just breaks the order without it we would have subject - we, after it verb - get, but instead we have verb - do, subject - we. What is the point of all this?